# How do I add this webservice to work in my C# app?

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio

I have a program I'm building for a college class that needs to use a webservice, but we never covered webservices in class...

Through research I've found that I need to add a service reference, but adding ?WSDL to the end like it tells me to do keeps on giving me the "error downloading metadata" error.

The webservice is mis.upb.pitt.edu/dixon/WebService.asmx

Comment: What is the "error downloading metadata"  error? Check the "Output" tab in visual studio. Is it a 404 error (can't find the medtadata)? Or something different? What do you get if you open the WSDL url in a broswer?

Comment: I was able to add this without an issue (VS2010). It is possibly an environmental issue: Internet Proxy etc.

Comment: It stops me right at the "Add Service Reference" dialogue with: "There was an error downloading metadata from the address. Please verify that you have entered a valid address"

Comment: When I try to access it in a web browser I just get a blank page. And of course the error in VS 2013. No proxy and my branch campus is right down the street. Thinking hard and emailing my professor about it, heh.

Comment: Did you preface it with `http`, eg, in a browser: http://mis.upb.pitt.edu/dixon/WebService.asmx, should give a webservice descripion page and http://mis.upb.pitt.edu/dixon/WebService.asmx?wsdl should give you a nice mess of XML. Clicking on the "Service Description" link on the first url should take you through to the WSDL. (Damn SO has taken the http out of the text in the links... click the links and get back to me!)

Comment: The regular one gives me a description, and the other gives me a blank page in firefox... looking at the code for the blank page it has a bunch of non-HTML code starting with <wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm=

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64910/discussion-between-jon-p-and-aarron-dixon).

Comment: I just closed VS and reopened it, and tried again, with the ?WSDL version, and... it added it no complaints. That might explain why it was tough... I think it was just a VS bug, lol. Sorry about that! I guess I'm off to figure out what to do next. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to close Virtual Studio and open it again. It worked fine after that!

I think that's a solution I should try earlier next time.